# Part identification help needed? Diode SO8 package with logo

Tags: pcb, components, identification

I've been trying to identify the following part. It is marked with the following logo:

[image]

I haven't come across this logo before, but the "P" and the fact that it is a likely a diode (see below) brings Panasonic to mind.

The part is as shown:

[image]

Its reference designator is "D12" so it is likely a diode array of some sort. The markings are: logo + "0551 STA". It appears to be connected between a transformer and a Broadcom 10/100 BASE-TX (ethernet) transceiver, specifically the BCM5221 ([Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/678/5221-PB06-R-693238.pdf)).

Can anyone identify the part or the logo as shown?

Thanks in advance.

Sam

Comment: That's not a datasheet...

Comment: It's likely a TVS diode array.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a product brief, it's just to help understanding the Broadcom chip's purpose at a glance.

Comment: That looks like the (very old) Phillips (now NXP) logo.

Comment: @peter that would surprise me. I.e. I'm almost certain this is not a Philips Logo. You don't happen to have a reference picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a bit of googling and have found that the logo is for Protek Devices.

And the datasheet can be found here: http://datasheet.octopart.com/ET721-LF-T7-Protek-datasheet-632479.pdf

The marking STA is shown on page 2. I would say that 0551 is a batch number. Sometimes surface mount component markings can be confusing as to which characters form the part number and which ones are either date codes or batch numbers.

FYI, the search term I used to find this was "diode array marking STA" it was the 8th result on the first page. But there were a few hits that would also get you the information you want.

Comment: Excellent first answer! Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: Great find! I thought I had tried all the combinations, it seems silly I didnt try that one. Thanks a lot.